# Spatie laravel-backup giving undesired file structure inside the output zip

Tags: laravel, laravel-backup

I installed `spatie/laravel-backup` version 6.16 and haven't changed anything inside the `backup.php` file. When I do `php artisan backup:run` I got the timestamp zip, I don't know why but the inside of the zip file looks like this:

(the inside of each folders are empty, all the files are stored side to side with the folders, not inside the folders...)
[image: the inside of each folders are empty]
[image: all the files are stored side to side with the folders, not inside the folders...]

My desired output is to be like these:

https://youtu.be/tdrZynKqrHM?t=290

https://youtu.be/2VoekC_RtbE?t=207

Anyone know how to solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind, I solved it by using another zip app (Winrar)

I immediately uninstall 7zip after that lol!